# How to add a background in spritekit

Tags: objective-c, image, background, sprite-kit

I've been working on a spritekit game lately and I'm really close to completing it. It's my first time using the library but I'm super excited to start getting the hang of it. I seem to be getting it just fine until I encountered my problem.

I was adding a background Image into my game and I got it to work just like this:

```
_background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background"];
[_background setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
[self addChild:_background];
```

My frame rate was staying at a very high 60 FPS but as soon as I add the background image it dips all the way to a terrible 30 FPS how could this be. There is only 3 nodes on the screen. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I bet you are testing on the simulator ...

Comment: Yes, iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit), Is there a problem with that?

Comment: you put the background, 30 fps, comment the addChild method and run again, 60 fps?

Comment: yep exactly. Dont know why

Comment: You can read here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556867/xcode-5-sprite-kit-examples-slow-simulator  - Google "SpriteKit Framerate Simulator" and that's the #1 result.

Comment: simulator is a software renderer