# How to set FPS in sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, frame-rate

I run my game on iphone simulator, the FPS is 30, and I run it on my real device, it is 60.
why they are different, how to set FPS in sprite kit?

```
      skView.showsFPS = YES; 
  skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FPS is usually slower on the simulator because the simulator is not as capable at handling the game as your device is.  If you want an accurate reading of your FPS, always use your device.

A more in depth answer is given here.... 
[iOS Simulator games run very slow (low fps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556867/xcode-5-sprite-kit-examples-slow-simulator)