# Spritekit - dynamically adding children slows performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, frame-rate

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize my game.  I have a lot of turrets etc shooting out physics bodies.  The game is playable but can dip into 50 or 45 fps.  I've figured out that it is related to adding objects to my scene on the fly.

for example.  when my turret is shooting it runs this code

```
func shootBlaster(){
    let blaster = Projectile(color: SKColor.cyanColor(), size: CGSize(width: convertNum(3), height: convertNum(3)))
    blaster.name = "blaster"
    blaster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: blaster.size)
    blaster.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CategoryEnemyProjectile
    blaster.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CategoryShip | CategoryShipShield
    blaster.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0



    let fireAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        let angle = self.turret.base.zRotation + self.zRotation
        let velocity = CGPoint(angle: angle) * convertNum(420)
        let vector = CGVectorMake(velocity.x, velocity.y)
        let blas = blaster.copy() as Projectile
        blas.wpnDmg = 10
        blas.position = self.gameScene.gameLayer.convertPoint(self.turret.barrelPos, fromNode: self.turret.base)
        self.gameScene.gameLayer.addChild(blas)
        blas.physicsBody!.velocity = vector
        blas.zRotation = blas.physicsBody!.velocity.angle

        blas.runAction(SKAction.removeFromParentAfterDelay(1))
    })

    let recoilAction = SKAction.moveByX(-5, y: 0, duration: 0.08)
    let reverseRecoil = recoilAction.reversedAction()

    self.turret.barrel.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(
        SKAction.sequence([
            recoilAction,
            fireAction,
            reverseRecoil
        ])
    ,count: self.blasterNum))

}
```

you can see that I'm adding a "blaster" inside of each of the fireAction blocks.  I've noticed games with better performance are rarely adding children at runtime.  It seems best to have everything pre-loaded.  It makes sense that loading resources during runtime would put a strain on things, but what is the alternative?  Do I need to add everything to the scene ahead of time and somehow hide and show it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With any kind of shooting game where you have numerous projectiles you want to utilize "pooling". Create a pool of projectiles and reuse them as opposed to creating new ones when you need them.

Comment: so you think "addChild" is not really the issue.  It's the instantiation of the objects dynamically?

Comment: Definitely. Create a pool, reuse those objects. Problem solved :)

Comment: addChild can play a role too but if you pool nodes you would never remove them as children in th first place, you'd simply change their hidden property

Comment: in the case of bullets flying around the screen.. i'd never remove them?  what would i do?  change them to hidden and reset their position?

Comment: this was great.  i do see a tiny frame drop when i'm adding children.  but with pooling its about a 0.5 frame drop vs a 5 frame drop

Comment: addChild/removeChild definitely has overhead as compared to changing the hidden property. But, 99% of the issue is creation itself.

Comment: Pooling made no difference in my game. Neither did using the hidden flag vs adding and removing them from their parent node. I have yet to figure out what causes my 10 to 15 fps drop with only 10 bullets on the scene. I tried turning physics off, particle effects off, physics off, sound effects off. Nothing has helped. Draw count doesn't increase. When profiling, my main update method only uses 1.4% of the games cycles and the physics engine only uses 4%. Yet still, it slows and hitches.

Comment: Are you testing on device or simulator? If simulator, simple answer is "that's why". If on a device, you have something else very wrong in your code. Pooling isn't a magical fix for any framerate drop, but it was a solution for this question.

Comment: If in simulator : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556867/ios-simulator-games-run-very-slow-low-fps