# SKLightNode slows game when sprites have zRotation set

Tags: sprite-kit, ios9

I am working on a SpriteKit game project that was running at 60 FPS in iOS 8.4

Since iOS 9, I am seeing performance drop to about 30FPS on iPhone 4S.

I have sprites (about 20-30 at once in a scene) that have their zRotation property set to something greater than 0.0 (e.g. 120).

When I add a SKLightNode and configure it to light up the sprites, I get my performance drop. Running Apple's performance tools only leeds me to some system libraries related to SKView Rendering.

If I set the zRotation property of the sprites to 0.0, the game runs at 60 FPS once again. My gave uses rotation heavily, so keeping it at 0.0 is not an option for me.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rado.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19562222/4078517

Comment: Thanks, I understand if FPS is low on simulator. Since iOS 9, I stated experiencing it in the real devices too.

Answer (score 0):

this seems an 9.0.x related issue - check https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/65479#65479 for details or see below the piece that is most important:

```
I just tested iOS9.1 beta 2 and SKLightNode performance is back to normal *relief*
```

btw. I experienced this fps drop even with rotation set to 0 :)

Comment: I finally see significant improvements with iOS 9.2 Beta 1.. That bug was crazy.